# Can I access the StartupEventArgs from anywhere other than the App_Startup event handler?

Tags: wpf, command-line, parameters

Are the command line parameters accessible from anywhere in the application other than the App_Startup event handler?  Can I get to them through something like App.Current?

Comment: I have been looking for the solution for the same question. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in silverlight.net
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/215616/511157.aspx#511157

Comment: Kindly provide the exact link.

Comment: I will look for it, in the mean time, have you tried Application.Current.Host.InitParams to get the parameters.